# How to sort a list using only 1 button multiply times in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm a beginner at coding in general so I don't have much experience. Is there a way I can use one button to sort/filter a list of cards that I have, multiple times by alphabetic order, type, element, class, etc. I have try different ways but as I said I'm still fairly new. Here is my code in XAML:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <SearchBar Grid.Row="0" 
                       Grid.Column="0" 
                       x:Name="CardSearch"
                       TextChanged="SearchPressed"
                       Placeholder="Search Cards..."
                       CancelButtonColor="Red"
                       TextColor="Green"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Text="Sort by"
                    Clicked="CardSorted"
                    />
        </Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="CardsListView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" 
                              Detail="{Binding Rest}"
                              TextColor="ForestGreen"
                              DetailColor="MediumPurple"
                              />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

and my c#:

```
 public partial class CardsPage : ContentPage
{
    public CardsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CardsListView.ItemsSource = App.cardsList;
    }

    void SearchPressed(object sender, EventArgs w)
    {
        var cardListSearched = App.cardsList.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(CardSearch.Text));
        CardsListView.ItemsSource = cardListSearched;
    }

     void CardSorted(object sender, EventArgs f)
    {
        //Need help right here
    }

    private async void BuilderPage(object sender, EventArgs b)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DeckBuilder());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int sort = 0;

void CardSorted(object sender, EventArgs f)
{
   switch (sort) {
     case 0:
       CardsListView.ItemsSource =  App.cardsList.OrderBy(a => a.Name);
       break;
     case 1:
       CardsListView.ItemsSource =  App.cardsList.OrderBy(a => a.Age);
       break;
     ...
   }

   sort += 1;
   if (sort >= max) sort = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. With is and the other comment you had earlier it will help a lot.